# Add a line to the git commit message while I'm editing code

Tags: git, vim

While editing code in VIM I would like to add small one-line notes to the Git Commit message. Sometimes I find it simpler to to fix a small issue right when I see it rather than to comment it or document it for a future fix. However, I still would like the change to appear in the comment log.

Right now I am running `:!echo Did something neat >> g` and I am using the content of the `g` file in my git comment. Before I write a VIM macro to write to the file, does Git / VIM have a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of adding additional comments to a commit message for small fixes that you come across while working, you can just selectively stage the fix with `git add --patch` (or `git add -p`) and create a commit for it, then continue working on the rest of your code.

Not only do you give each fix its own commit by doing this, you also help keep the commits in your history representing logical units of work, i.e. changes that logically belong together, instead of having a big commit with a bunch of unrelated changes in it.

From [the Git docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add):

> `-p`
>   `--patch`
>   Interactively choose hunks of patch between the index and the work tree and add them to the index. This gives the user a chance to
>   review the difference before adding modified contents to the index.
>
> This effectively runs add --interactive, but bypasses the initial
>   command menu and directly jumps to the patch subcommand. See
>   “Interactive mode” for details.

Pro Git also describes this so-called [interactive staging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging).

Comment: +1 for git add -p. As it is said; Git Patch is the best feature in Git that you didn't know about.

Comment: For any Vim users that like the power of `git add --patch`, I would also recommend Tim Pope’s [fugitive plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive). I have not used `git add --patch` (or `git add -i`) since I installed fugitive. For example, `:Gdiff` while editing a tracked file will open a Vim diff-mode split between the current buffer and the version in the index. Effectively, you can directly edit index entires while having the option to use Vim diff commands to sling around whole chunks.

Comment: This would be a terrific solution if I could do it _while editing code_. As it is, it actually adds more work because I would have to configure each diff section to commit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Vim register instead.

```
:let @n = "Did something neat\n"
...
" Uppercase register name appends:
:let @N = "Did another clever thing\n"
```

You can then insert the contents via `:put n`, or `"np`, etc. Usually, the register contents are saved across Vim invocations (in the *viminfo* file), so it's as good as your temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using other alternatives to add metadata to the commit, such as 'git notes' or see: http://www.tikalk.com/DevOps/commit-metadata-tag-implementation/